# How to make a link within a text in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use Thymeleaf, to generate something like this:

```html
<p>Follow <a href="...">this</a> link</p>
```

All the text comes from a resource provider (Java resource bundle), and the link contains values from the Thymeleaf context.

I can separate the blocks of text, but that's ugly:

```html
<p>
  <span th:text="#{resource1}">Follow </span>
  <a th:href="${link}" th:text="#{resource2}">this</a>
  <span th:text="#{resource3}"> link<span>
</p>
```

How do I do this nicely?

Comment: You can use `th:utext` for this purpose - see [Unescaped Text](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#unescaped-text). But I would not recommend using that - it has security implications, if user-provided data can be included in the tag. I actually prefer splitting up the data using `<span>` the way you show in the question. It avoids mixing plain text and tags together. And you don't need to use `th:utext`.

Comment: @andrewjames That would require me to have the HTML in my resource file, and pass the link property as a parameter. That doesn't sound like a better solution...

Comment: ... which is also why the suggested duplicate isn't good enough: It suggests an *even worse* solution, not a better one.

Comment: The duplicate link is intended to show the existence of `th:utext` - not that you have to use it in the exact way specified in the answer - just that it exists, and can be used. Sorry for implying a worse solution - that was not my intention. You can use `th:utext` in the way shown in the documentation I link to in my first comment (it's just that I wouldn't recommend it).

Comment: Just to add: I take your point about the dupe - and I have retracted it.

Comment: Why would you just rephrase "Follow <this> link" to something like "Click the following link:" <link>? This simple approach would allow you to separate sentence, link title, and URL from each other. Resource files would include separate items, which are easy to translate for any international language. Not every time the development team supposed to do the work (weird coding, compromise security, etc), sometimes it's better to kick the documentation team to do their part and rephrase the mock-up you probably have.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov That works in some languages, but not in others. I'd like this to be flexible enough so that all supported languages can make it flow nicely.

Comment: Interesting, maybe I am not aware, would you provide an example of such language, just out of curiosity? We have 32 languages, including one RTL and this approach works all the time, at least for those languages.